# What should toString be formatted like when used for debugging/logging classes/objects?

Tags: java, tostring

I override toString method to print out members of my class. What is common format say used by large projects...
classname():variable name1=variable value1 comma separated?

Any links to some open source code would be great.

Also, it looks like .NET has actually specific method for this task:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name} [date={Date}, value={Value}]")]
public class MyClass {
```

In java, CustomClass.toString is used for logging?

Comment: Most IDEs I've used have an automated toString declaration. Typically, if you are debugging, as long as you're getting the information in a readable format, it's good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on the class in question, and what you consider relevant.

Since debuggers can show you all the fields and their values, you don't really need `toString()` for that. It should instead be a *summary* of relevant information, depending on the intended purpose.

Example: A `Person` class holds fields such as `id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `phoneNumber`, `addressLine1`, `addressLine2`, `city`, `state`, `zipcode`.

Is it relevant to show *all* those values in the `toString()` result? If yes, use a format like this:

```
Person[id=1,firstName=John,lastName=Doe,phoneNumber=555-555-0127,addressLine1=123 Main St.,city=Queens,state=NY,zipcode=11354]
```

However, think about the result if you have a `List<Person>`:

```
[Person[id=1,firstName=John,lastName=Doe,phoneNumber=555-555-0127,addressLine1=123 Main St.,city=Queens,state=NY,zipcode=11354], Person[id=2,firstName=Jane,lastName=Smith,...]]
```

It would be better for such uses, if the `toString()` method simply help *identify* the objects, e.g. just name (first + last) and maybe `id`:

```
[John Doe (1), Jane Smith (2)]
```

So, as I said in the beginning: *It depends.*

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of overriding the toString class is to format it however you want it. Yes, the format is typically an object or class name with a comma-separated list of all of the fields that you would like displayed with an accompanying name for the fields (e.g. 'date='datevalue). toString is a very useful debugging tool if you write the method to display the variables that you are testing.